# how to check if FirstName is empty then fill it from full name in excel file?

Tags: string, excel, concatenation

I have a excel file, need to check if firstname is null or blank then extract the first name from full name column for example:

Full Name is :: Ram Singh
then i want to Ram in First name column.

I have tried the following formula but it returns always 0 to me as value of firstname.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(F3), F3, C3)
```

FirstName is in F3 and Full Name is C3.

Second Thing i want same thing for Full Name: if Fullname is empty then it concatenate the firstname and lastname

please help me how can i achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will extract the first name:

```
=LEFT(C6, FIND(" ",C6)-1)
```

and this will extract the last:

```
=MID(C6, FIND(" ",C6)+1,100)
```

Of course it will only work if there is one first name.

If I understood what you want you can use:
First name: `=IF(ISBLANK(F3), F3, LEFT(C6, FIND(" ",C6)-1))`